# High quality Plot 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following definitions

```
a1 = Sqrt[2 + 2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
  Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]]; 

a2 = Sqrt[2 + 2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
  Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]];

a3 = Sqrt[2 + 2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
  Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]];

delta = ((a1 + a2 + a3)^2 - 1)*((a1 - a2 + a3)^2 - 
     1)*((a1 + a2 - a3)^2 - 1)*((a1 - a2 - a3)^2 - 1);

beta = 2 a1^2 + 2 a2^2 + 2 a3^2 + 2 a1^2 a2^2 + 2 a1^2 a3^2 + 
   2 a2^2 a3^2 - a1^4 - a2^4 - a3^4 - Sqrt[delta] - 1;
```

I want to do a high quality Plot3D on a region function as following

```
Plot3D[{1/2 Log[(beta/(8 a1^2))]}, {r, -1, 1}, {θ, 0.01 π, 
  1.99 π}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{r, θ}, 
   0 < Sqrt[
     2 + 2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
       Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]] - 
     1/Sqrt[2] (√(((-3 - 
              2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
               Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])^2 + 
            2 (7 + 6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]) + 
            Abs[-3 - 
               2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                Cosh[2 r] + 
                 Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]] √((-3 - 
                  2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                   Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])^2 + 
                8 (7 + 6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]
                     Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] + 
                    Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])))/(7 + 
            6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
             Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])))], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 Mesh -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
 Ticks -> {{5, -2.5, -1, 0, 1, 2.5, 5}, {0, Pi, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}, {0, 0.40, 
    0.45}}]
```

then, I obtain

[image]

However, when I extend the PlotRange, I obtain "noise" at the tail of the plot; that is,

```
Plot3D[{1/2 Log[(beta/(8 a1^2))]}, {r, -5.1, 5.1}, {θ, 
  0.01 π, 1.99 π}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{r, θ}, 
   0 < Sqrt[
     2 + 2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
       Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]] - 
     1/Sqrt[2] (√(((-3 - 
              2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
               Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])^2 + 
            2 (7 + 6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]) + 
            Abs[-3 - 
               2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                Cosh[2 r] + 
                 Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]] √((-3 - 
                  2 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
                   Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])^2 + 
                8 (7 + 6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]]
                     Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] + 
                    Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])))/(7 + 
            6 Sqrt[Cosh[2 r] - Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]] Sqrt[
             Cosh[2 r] + Cos[2 θ] Sinh[2 r]])))], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 Mesh -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
 Ticks -> {{5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5}, {0, Pi, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}, {0, 
    0.40, 0.45}}]
```

[image]

So, **there is a way to obtain the Plot3D without noise at the tails, at a wider plotRange?**

Comment: You used the option `PlotPoints->40`. Did you try to increase it, say, to 100? 200?

Comment: Yes, up to 500; however, the output does not improve its quality; instead, my PC slows down!

Comment: You could try a `ListPlot3D` where you use non-uniform sampling to get higher-resolution data near the discontinuities

Comment: Set `PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, BoundaryStyle -> None` we can get a relative smooth surface.